# c# RegistryKey double loop?

Tags: c#, registry, registrykey

if I run below code I would get:

```
 PG_ID_N_1_NA_ID_1,
 PG_ID_N_2_NA_ID_1,
 PG_ID_N_3_NA_ID_1,
 PG_ID_N_4_NA_ID_1
```

[image]

However what I would like to do is to get the value of `FriendlyName  REG_SZ` under each of those keys.

```
RegistryKey r = Registry.LocalMachine;
r = r.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\{C641C770-FAAC-44ED-9C73-48D1B5E59200}\NDIS&VEN_1924&DEV_0803&SUBSYS_62271924", false);
foreach (string s in r.GetSubKeyNames())
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
r.Close();
```

Comment: are you trying to return the names of the applications that belong to those SubKeyNames...? will link help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324920/regedit-shows-keys-that-are-not-listed-using-getsubkeynames or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089148/get-value-of-registry-key-c-sharp

Comment: screenshot attached. I would like to get the value of "FriendlyName" which is available on each  of those PGs.

Comment: instead of r.GetSubKeyNames() will r.GetValueNames() work

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
RegistryKey r = Registry.LocalMachine;
r = r.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\{C641C770-FAAC-44ED-9C73-48D1B5E59200}\NDIS&VEN_1924&DEV_0803&SUBSYS_62271924", false);  
foreach (string s in r.GetSubKeyNames())
{
    using (RegistryKey subKey = r.OpenSubKey(s))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(subKey.GetValue("FriendlyName"));
    }
}
r.Close();
```

I don't have a compiler on this computer so the code above might be crap.